# Android SQLite: Is it a good practice to call getColumnIndex when retrieving values from a table?

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-sqlite

Right now, I have my code looking like this:

**SqlTables.java:**

```
// Separate file
public enum SqlTables {
    TABLE_1("table_1"),
    .
    .
    .
    TABLE_N("table_n");
    final String name;
    private SqlTables(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Table1Columns.java:**

```
// Separate file
public enum Table1Columns {
    ...
}
```

**SqlDatabaseInterface.java:**

```
Cursor c = db.query(SqlTables.TABLE_1.toString(), null...);
final int indexId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
        Table1Columns.ID.toString());
final int indexName = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
        Table1Columns.NAME.toString());
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    final String id = c.getString(indexId);
    final String name = c.getString(indexName);
}
```

I did not find any documentation regarding how Android mapped columns to indices, so while I've confirmed that it is based on the order in which the columns were stated in the query, I do not have a guarantee that this will work 100% of the time, or that future updates will keep this behavior. The benefits of using `getColumnIndexOrThrow(...)` is the guarantee that my indices will always be correct, so long as the columns they reference are included in the query. The downside is that, besides the tedium, it makes my code much harder to read and greatly increases the length of my methods. On the other hand, I could just specify the indices without calling `getColumnsIndexOrThrow`, and that'd shorten my code, but the lack of documentation makes it feel wrong.

Comment: I think you have the general idea. Using `getColumnIndex()` and `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` is longer to type, but safer if you ever reorder or create minor changes in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you definitely should **not** hard code the column index values into your code. If you do, your database will be nearly impossible to manage (since making changes to the table could cause the index values to change).

From what I can tell, your code is difficult to read because:

1. You are literring your code with unnecessary calls to `toString()`. Just get rid of them... they are completely redundant.
2. You are using the `final` keyword way too much and its cluttering your code. This should be used as a precaution in situations where you might accidentally change the value of a variable. This is not one of those situations...
3. You are spreading simple statements across multiple lines. Just use one line and it'll make it a lot easier to read.

That said, there is technically nothing wrong with any of the above coding practices. I'm just saying, if you really care about making your code easy to read then you might want to consider them as suggestions.

Comment: `If you do, making changes to your database will be nearly impossible to manage.` -- Because...

Comment: Because if he ever changed his database schema (i.e. by adding a column to one of his tables), there is no guarantee that the integer values will remain the same. A subtle bug like this could cost him hours of wasted time debugging. That's why it is very, very good practice to check the column index's integer values at runtime during the program's execution.

Comment: Lol, well... until someone can point out the flaw in my reasoning, I stand by this answer and remain 100% confident that this answer is **correct**.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, and by the way, the [**author of this book**](http://books.google.com/books?id=YDeNQia3BwQC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=getcolumnindex+android+hard+code&source=bl&ots=f8If-JJOVP&sig=yZqzkrx6Ox6XGWjaSGpa37UEB4o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aGrmT-Zjx_jSAZO66M0J&ved=0CFkQ6AEwBTgK) agrees with me too. :)

Comment: I was just pointing out that your answer was not finished. :P

Comment: Haha, ok... well that's good because for a second there I was like, "hmm... is this a trick question?". Either way, I've updated my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the verbose answer. I appreciate it. Just to clarify, I added some code to show why I need calls to `Object.toString()`. I placed my table names and column names in `enums`, and the compiler (or eclipse, at least) complains without them. My index names usually make the calls exceed 80 characters, so I broke up the calls to reflect what my code generally looks like. As for the excessive calls to `final`, I don't know, but it makes me feel safe haha.

Comment: Take a look at the [Google I/O 2011](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleDatabase.java) source code... it'll give you a good idea of how you should be designing your database classes/constants. I wouldn't use `enum`s for the column names... instead, I would provide `public static final String` constants in my database class. Defining your columns as `enum`s is just adding an additional step to the process and doesn't provide any benefits over using `String` constants. Does that makes sense?